# Get CircleCI environment variables into Swift via Fastlane

Tags: swift, xcode, environment-variables, circleci, fastlane

I want to add some secrets to CircleCI environment variables so that its not hardcoded in my project for security and so that we can cycle them as needed too.

I know I can access the environment variables from Fastlane with `ENV["SOME_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_KEY"]` and from what I understand I can pass that into `build_app`'s `xcargs` parameter. This is supposedly then available in build phase in Xcode.

eg `build_app(..., xcargs: "Testing='SUCCESS'")`

I cannot seem to find much documentation on this but I did see in a couple questions that you should be able to add a step to Build Phases and then in the script you export an environment variable that can be used in code. I tried `export TESTING=${Testing}` and when I try access that in code it (with `ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["TESTING"]`) it comes back as `nil`.

I was not convinced that my script was actually doing anything so hardcoded it in the build phase to `export TESTING="SUCCESS"` and even then `ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["TESTING"]` comes back as `nil`, just to be sure I added a breakpoint and printed `ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment.keys` and the `TESTING` key is not present

I have tried running from Fastlane directly with both the hardcoded value in the build phase and the variable that should come back from Fastlane and, despited me having `print`s in the unit test and `echo`s in the script, nothing prints (It does print `▸ Running script 'Set up environment variables from CircleCI'` but not my debugging echos where I print a string just to see where I am and try print all the environment variables and doesn't print anything for the unit test)

Am I missing something very obvious here? Surely it shouldn't be this complicated?

Thanks in advance